# Jaco Arm MoveIt

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking to integrate the Jaco arm into moveit.  I have the arm simulating and planning correctly in moveit, and I am now trying to integrate the plan on the real arm.  Unfortunately the moveit documentation is focused on the PR2 and not generalized to adapting to other platforms. Does anyone have any incite as to how to integrate moveit on an actual platform?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63036/jaco-arm-moveit/) by [mdedonato](https://answers.ros.org/users/4929/mdedonato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-05-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a ready to use Jaco Moveit Package with included jaco_driver I have created based on Sankar Natarajan's work:
https://github.com/fivef/JacoROS/tree/hydro

See this Question if you want to create one by yourself:
[How to proceed with using Moveit if you're not working on a PR2?](http://answers.ros.org/question/64236/how-to-proceed-with-using-moveit-if-youre-not-working-on-a-pr2/#64285)

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IliaBaranov](https://answers.ros.org/users/11601/iliabaranov/) on 2014-02-03**:
Hey,

Your github code seems deleted. Any chance you would put it back?

**Comment by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) on 2014-02-04**:
Sorry, I have deleted this repo yesterday but had no time to upload my new one. Thanks for the reminder to update the links. The new one is catkinized and running on hydro. Just follow the instructions in the readme to get your Jaco up and running with MoveIt!. Improvements appreciated!

**Comment by [IliaBaranov](https://answers.ros.org/users/11601/iliabaranov/) on 2014-02-05**:
Excellent! Thanks